# How can I add something to the productFlavors which I can read from java code

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I was trying to build multiple apks with different channel names, and I need to read the channel name in my java code. So I'm trying to work with productFlavors, currently what I'm trying to do is add the following code to my build.gradle

```
 productFlavors {
    GooglePlay {
    }

    Amazon {
    }
}

sourceSets {
    GooglePlay {
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets-GooglePlay', 'assets']
    }

    Amazon {
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets-Amazon', 'assets']
    }
}
```

And I aslo add a file name `channelName` to the two assets folder `assets-GooglePlay` and `assets-Amazon`. What I'm hoping is the generated apk will contains this `channelName` file, but the fact is it doesn't exists. So how can I deal with this problem? Thanks

I'm currently working with Gradle 2.2.1

Comment: so you just want a string to be different in your 2 flavors is that right?

Comment: yes, that should be enough, but I need to read the string from my java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a more simple solution

```
productFlavors {
    GooglePlay {
        buildConfigField "String", "ChannelName", "\"GooglePlay\""
    }
    Amazon {
        buildConfigField "String", "ChannelName", "\"Amazon \""
    }
}
```

Then access the channel name via `BuildConfig.ChannelName`

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve can be done by having 2 separates string files, one for each flavor.

So at the moment you probably have one file called strings.xml in src/main/res/values. Let's say that this file contain the string you want for GooglePlay, then what you need to do is create another one in src/Amazon/res/values, that will contain the string for Amazon.

Once this is done, you can access that string from the code by calling `getResources().getString(R.string.STRING_NAME)` from inside an activity.

Answer (score 0):

add resValue in you each productFlavor is also a artful method.